# How can I implement the array feature in a select menu?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dreamweaver

So I am using a questionnaire with multiple select lists, to classify our users into different groups of 5, and we are also working on an algorithm to out them into different groups. But I am having trouble with the select list, as I am not sure how to store the selected value into arrays. So how can I use/implement the array feature in my questionnaire?

(Sorry for thePoorly constructed question, I am kind of new in the programming language business)

P.S. I'm using the Dreamweaver cs6 to construct the entire website including this questionnaire, and here's one of the question I am using in the questionnaire

```
< p >What time zone are you in?          
      < select name="select" id="select">
         <option value="0">GMT -12</option>
             ....
         <option value="23">GMT +11 </option>
         <option value="0">GMT +12 </option>
      </select>
< /p >
```

Comment: you mean you have 5 select lists having the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Add `[]` to the name.

```
<select name="select[]" id="select">
```